# I need to calculate the mean value of an array in a dimension-wise fashion

Tags: python, c++, mean

I started learning C++, and have more experience in python.

I have the following code written in python which returns from a 3D array a 2D array of the mean value in the Z-dimension

```
import numpy as np

def mean_py_st_ov(array):
    x = array.shape[1]
    y = array.shape[2]

    values = np.empty((x,y), type(array[0][0][0]))
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):       
            values[i][j] = ((np.mean(array[:, i, j])))

    return values
```

I am working on the following code to return a mean in the ndimension of an 3d Array, but by now.. I am struggling trying to get the i-j elements in every dimension at a time.

```
// C++ program to print elements of Three-Dimensional 
// Array 
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    // initializing the 3-dimensional array 
    int x[3][2][2] = 
    { 
        { {0,1}, {2,3} },
         {{4,5}, {6,7}}, 
         {{8,9}, {10,11} } 
    }; 

    // output each element's value 
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) 
            { 
                cout << "Element at x[" << k << "][" << i 
                    << "][" << j << "] = " << x[k][i][j] 
                    << endl; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

I receive the following output

```
Element at x[0][0][0] = 0
Element at x[0][0][1] = 1
Element at x[0][1][0] = 2
Element at x[0][1][1] = 3
Element at x[1][0][0] = 4
Element at x[1][0][1] = 5
Element at x[1][1][0] = 6
Element at x[1][1][1] = 7
Element at x[2][0][0] = 8
Element at x[2][0][1] = 9
Element at x[2][1][0] = 10
Element at x[2][1][1] = 11
```

What I want is to get let say... the first element of 1array with first element of second array,then second element in 1array with second element of 2array. All examples I went through the web only iterate in this fashion i,j,k and it prints all the elements in order which is not what I want, because I need to get the mean in the Z-axis in the 3D array.

I need the following output:

```
    Element at x[0][0][0] = 0
    Element at x[1][0][0] = 4
    Element at x[2][0][0] = 8
    Element at x[0][0][1] = 1
    Element at x[1][0][1] = 5
    Element at x[2][0][1] = 9
    Element at x[0][1][0] = 2
    Element at x[1][1][0] = 6
    Element at x[2][1][0] = 10
    Element at x[0][1][1] = 3
    Element at x[1][1][1] = 7
    Element at x[2][1][1] = 11
```

Could you help me please!

Thank you very much

PD: As additional bonus point: I would like to get the mean value of every element in a Z-axis and be able to produce the following 2D array as output. 
    int x[2][2] = {{4,5}{6,7}}

Comment: Your array dimensions are (2,3,2) but your nested loop bounds are (2,2,3).

Comment: Sorry you are right.. I edited the loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to do. Can you add an example *correct* output?

Comment: I edited my code, so you can get a better idea what I want to accomplish. I hope it's clearer now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your for-loops to this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
        {
            cout << "Element at x[" << k << "][" << i
                 << "][" << j << "] = " << x[k][i][j]
                 << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The index that changes faster should be in the most-inner for and the index that changes less than others should be in the most outer loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem. I will keep working on that, to find the way to calculate the mean of this slice of three elements and plug them into a 2D array.